# Conditional Regex Templating

Tags: regex, regex-group

I'd like to use Regex to include or exclude conditional texts on my templates.

A simple template:

```
#IF {{Placeholder}}
If true the text should remain, else it should be deleted
#ENDIF
```

On the first run i replace the placeholder with a simple true or false string:

```
#IF false
If true the text should remain, else it should be deleted
#ENDIF
```

On the second run i apply the conditions with the following Regex:

```
Regex.Replace(input, "(?s)#IF false.*?#ENDIF\r\n", "", RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

If the placeholder is "false" the full text block will be removed as expected.

What is missing now is the "true" condition, a Regex that keeps the inner texts and removes just the "#IF true" and "#ENDIF" lines **for this group**:

```
If true the text should remain, else it should be deleted
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you really have to invent your own template framework?

Comment: This is a horrible and misguided idea, but your `if true` part wants just to capture everything up to `#ENDIF` and replace the string with the captured part: `r = Regex.Compile("(?s)#IF true(.*?)#ENDIF\r\n");r.Replace(input, m => m.Groups[1].Value);`. But again, there are good templating systems already. Use one of these instead.

Comment: Thanks for you help :) Well i know that there are alot of templating frameworks out there, but i just need a simple solution for a simple problem without any overhead and performance issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just capture the line between IF and ENDIF when true, and use its value as replacement:

```
(?s)#IF\s*false.*?#ENDIF|#IF\s*true\R(.+?)\R#ENDIF
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dgHEY3/2)

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, assumption what I made here is no matter what #ENDIF is going to get deleted. If it is true comment will be deleted and if false whole block. So considering this made a Regex. It fulfills both your requirement. If true, just delete the comment and if false delete whole block.

Regex:`'(?:(?:#IF\s(?:false)\n).*)|(?:#IF true\n)(?<=#IF true\n)|(?:#ENDIF)\n?'`

Here is the link to the example with the data you gave here.
https://regex101.com/r/cFy11t/9